# Error inserting data from Polars to SQL // (Invalid character value for cast specification (0))

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, python-polars

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this error forever but can't seem to get my head around it.

I have a simple Python script to take data from CSV and dump it to a staging table in SQL Server. Using Polars I add a "process_time" field:

```
 data = data.with_columns(
        (
            pl.datetime(
                year=current_date.year,
                month=current_date.month,
                day=current_date.day,
                hour=current_date.hour,
                minute=current_date.minute,
                second=current_date.second,
            )
        ).alias("process_time"),
```

I am then using the polars.to_sql() method to load it to SQL (relevant SQL schema below):

```
...
...
[process_time] [datetime] NULL,
...
```

I'm receiving this error. When I tried to manually load the processed flat file into SQL server it specifically mentioned potential data loss in the process_time field.

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')
```

What is driving me crazy is that the processing portion is a function, and worked on last months file. Nothing has changed anywhere this month, but now for some reason it's throwing this error.

I don't see any empty rows, NULL values or anything like that. And I'm assigning the "process_time" variable as it's own column, so each row should have the exact same value.

Looking at the unique values for this column, I'm confirming they're all the same and in a datetime format already - below is the output from calling unique on the field in Polars.

```
import_time
datetime[μs]
2023-11-08 14:21:33
```

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT IN REPLY TO DEAN:

Result after calling `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)`and then `.unique()` on the field in question

```
<ArrowExtensionArray>
[Timestamp('2023-11-08 15:57:45')]
Length: 1, dtype: timestamp[us][pyarrow]
```

Polars Version Info

```
--------Version info---------
Polars:              0.19.12
Index type:          UInt32
Platform:            Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Python:              3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

----Optional dependencies----
adbc_driver_sqlite:  <not installed>
cloudpickle:         <not installed>
connectorx:          <not installed>
deltalake:           <not installed>
fsspec:              <not installed>
gevent:              <not installed>
matplotlib:          <not installed>
numpy:               1.26.1
openpyxl:            <not installed>
pandas:              2.1.2
pyarrow:             13.0.0
pydantic:            <not installed>
pyiceberg:           <not installed>
pyxlsb:              <not installed>
sqlalchemy:          2.0.22
xlsx2csv:            <not installed>
xlsxwriter:          <not installed>
```

Comment: nothing changed? did you upgrade polars or any other packages by any chance?

Comment: Nope - that's the strange thing. I also process other files with the same function, to add the process_time and then import to SQL with the same schema, and they all work as expected.  Super strange.

Comment: post `pl.show_versions()` please. Also, try to convert your df to pandas with `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)` and see if there's a loss of data in that step.

Comment: Thanks Dean - I edited the original question.

Comment: You say you're using polars's `to_sql` but it hasn't had that method for many versions and you're reporting 0.19.12 which doesn't have that method. Also when you do `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)` it doesn't alter it in place so you'd do something like `df.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)['process_time'].drop_duplicates()` as pandas doesn't have a `.unique()` method. Ultimately though, polars doesn't really natively write to databases even when you use `.write_database` it just converts to pandas under the hood and uses the pandas `to_sql`

Comment: You're right, my mistake. It's been so long since I wrote the script. I'm doing `Polars Df.to_pandas().to_sql()`

Is it normal that the function would work perfectly fine on other files, but not on a specific one?

Comment: Have you been able to capture the submitted query using Extended Events or SQL Profiler? I'm totally guessing here that pyarrow is somehow serializing the timestamp as a string, instead of sending it as a binary datetime, and that your SQL Server session could be using the DMY dateformat. To see why that might matter take a look at `@example1` in the first batch here... [https://dbfiddle.uk/WrLSneUB](https://dbfiddle.uk/WrLSneUB).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone seeing this in the future:

Even though when I tried manually uploading the data as a flat file to SQL Server it was flagging the "process_time" column as having the error, it ended up being another column causing the issue.

I ended up loading the data into SQL as all varchars and trying to convert each one to find the issue.